# Deny access to login page to authenticated user in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, authentication, forms-authentication, web-config

I'm working on an ASP.NET web application. We've got a login page (`index.aspx`), as well as a user's "home page", `userhome.aspx`. What's the most elegant way to deny a user to display `index.aspx` when they're logged in? At the moment, `index.aspx` can still be displayed by explicitly typing it into the browser address bar.

I tried the following (in `web.config`), but it does not work:

```
<location path="index.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny roles="MyUserRole" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

I could perform a manual redirection in code behind, but it looks pretty ugly to me. Thanks a lot for any more elegant approach :)

Cheers,
Matthias

Comment: why the manual redirection is pretty ugly ? I think that is better because if you add it on the config, then in the future you will forget it and you try to debug your code and you end up not know why you not see the index page.

Comment: The manual redirection is the best way I can think of doing this. Even if you denied access to the login page for logged in users, where would they get sent, by default back to the login page.

Comment: Agree with above comments. Its not ugly at all. That is what the Global.asax is designed for - in this case providing a hook-in to all requests.

Comment: Well, y'all may be right. I once saw code where any authorization was handled via `if(User.IsInRole("asdf"))` blocks in `Page_Load` (copied to each page). That's what made me say I really don't like it. Anyway, thanks to you, I'll have another look.